# Why does my var become undefined yet being set in the previous function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, var

Currently I'm trying to simulate a login / register form and I'm currently running in to a problem I can't seem to find an solution to where it says my "username" is undefined yet running the `onReg` function first.

```
var tempusername
var temppassword
var tempconpassword

var username
var password

function onReg(tempusername, temppassword, tempconpassword, username, password){

tempusername = document.querySelectorAll("[name=username]")[0].value
temppassword = document.querySelectorAll("[name=password]")[0].value
tempconpassword = document.querySelectorAll("[name=conpassword]")[0].value

if(temppassword == tempconpassword && tempusername.length>2 && temppassword.length>2 && tempconpassword.length>2 ){

    username = tempusername
    password = tempconpassword
    alert(username + " : " + password)

}
else if (password!=tempconpassword){
    alert("Password doesnt match or is to short!")

}
}

function onLogin(username,password) {
    alert("Does this work?" + username)
}
```

I think it might be because it's not a Global scope? and if so how could I come across doing it with this code?

Comment: Where did you call `onReg` ?

Comment: can you submit your code on jsfiddle.net so anyone in the community can look into it?

Comment: In my html <button class="req" onclick="onReg()">Create</button>

Comment: and what about the variables of onReg(tempusername, temppassword, tempconpassword, username, password)?

Comment: please share HTML and js  else submit your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vprn4eoz/

Answer (score 1):

`username` inside `onLogin` is a formal function parameter. You have to explicitly pass a value to it when calling `onLogin`.

```
var x = 'foo';
function checkX() {
    alert(x);
}  
function badCheckX(x) {
    alert(x);
}
checkX(); // 'foo'
badCheckX(); // undefined
badCheckX('bar'); // 'bar'
badCheckX(x); // 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `document.getElementById("[name=username]").value`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **variables** that have been declared already as **parameters** of a function. `username` and `password` are already declared as variables, so you should replace them with some other names. Try using `usernameX` and `passwordX` instead.

```
function onLogin(usernameX,passwordX) {

    // will alert the value of the first parameter (usernameX)
    alert("Does this work?" + usernameX) 

    //if you want to get the value of the variable 
    alert("Does this work?" + username)

}
```